PHP / IIS - Writing files to domain joined file server via UNC path
I am working within a domain environment, I have two servers:

server 1 - Windows / IIS
server 2 - Windows / File Server

I have a PHP script running on the IIS box which allows users to upload documents, this works fine when writing to a local folder on the server, however i now need to write the uploaded files to a network share.
I have tried everything i can think of and cannot get this to work, I consistently get Permission Denied errors when executing the script.
I have changed the Identity the ApplicationPool settings for this site to a domain user, said user DOES have the correct share/ntfs permissions on the share i am trying to write to, I have selected "Load Profile" under the ApplicationPool advanced settings to, the user/server can access the share fine within Windows Explorer.
I have triple/quadruple checked all NTFS / share permissions, but no joy.
Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Did you restart IIS after changing the identity of the pool?

Yes, i even rebooted the server.

You can try below steps to fix the issue:

please make sure share folder has permission to IIS computer name and
IIS_USR

change the Anonymous Authentication identity as Application Pool


